# How to show client the prototype without using a server for a web site

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have created a webpage that takes a skill survey of students of a particular college but they are not ready to give me server yet they would want to see the prototype first how to show them the prototype without using the server but just using the web page that I have created?

Comment: If you are running a business as a web developer then perhaps you need your own web server for hosting demos and prototypes? Then you could just send them a link. But otherwise, do you have a laptop that you can run a local server on and show them the prototype on the laptop?

Comment: How do I do that in my laptop I mean how can I host a server In my laptop I know Xampp and apache server

Comment: You "know" Apache? Well then you know that you can download and install it on your laptop for free.

Comment: Look into docker. You can run multiple servers on your computer and it's much lighter than a vm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A prototype shows how it works without actually working. So instead of getting real data, it can show fake data.

Your survey can show just two or three questions, and these questions can be hard-coded or loaded from a mock object, instead of loaded from the server. Also, instead of actually saving anything, it can just jump to the next question and show a text saying 'Thanks' when you are done.

That way, you can see if your survey has the right look and feel, and they can see that too. Also, it may make it a bit more clear to the server-builders what kind of implementation they need to make. A visible, 'clickable' prototype makes it easier to discuss details in the implementation.